# Altering python variable identifiers in a loop which defines a tkinter button

Tags: python, class, tkinter, variable-assignment

I've got a function in a class in which I am creating several tkinter buttons within, where the number of buttons and the button properties depends on a file (so I can't create a specific number of variables to hold the buttons).

The code I have looks like this (sparing the complexities of the whole code):

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

Class(GUI):

    def ButtonCreator(self):
        self.HomeworkList = open("Files\HWNameList.txt", "r")
        x = self.HomeworkList.readline()
        while not x == "END":
            x = x[0:-1]
            HomeworkFileName = str("Files\HW-" + x + ".txt")
            locals()["self.Button" + x] = tk.Button(master, text = x, command = lambda: self.DisplayHomeworkFile(FileName))
            locals()["self.Button" + x].pack()
            x = self.HomeworkList.readline()
        self.HomeworkList.close()

    def DisplayHomeworkFile(self, filename):
        os.startfile(filename)
```

The file I am opening looks like this...

```
HomeworkName1
HomeworkName2
HomeworkName3
END
```

When the code runs, it displays the buttons with the correct text written on them but when i click on them they only ever display the file who's file name is written last in the HomeworkList file. Not sure what I've done wrong.

If there is another way to achieve what I'm trying I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic beginners problem that comes from misunderstanding how lambda works. For this case you need to use `functools.partial`.

You also need to forget about modifying `locals()`. Make a list or dictionary to hold the button instances.

```
from functools import partial

def ButtonCreator(self):
    self.HomeworkList = open("Files\HWNameList.txt", "r")
    x = self.HomeworkList.readline()
    self.buttons = []
    while not x == "END":
        x = x[0:-1]
        HomeworkFileName = str("Files\HW-" + x + ".txt")
        btn = tk.Button(master, text = x, command = partial(self.DisplayHomeworkFile, HomeworkFileName))
        btn.pack()
        self.buttons.append(btn)
        x = self.HomeworkList.readline()
    self.HomeworkList.close()
```